# fs.readFileSync with a full file path causes 504 error

Tags: node.js, node.js-fs

I currently have an express server listening on port 5001

```
const port = 5001
http.createServer(app).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on ${port}`)
});
```

In this server I use a route:

```
app.use('/preview/:id', routes);
```

I get the route like so:

```
const { generatePreview } = require('../preview')
router.get('/preview/:id', generatePreview);
```

With in my generatePreview method I want read a file which I attempt to do with fs.readFileSync

I first resolve the full

```
exports.generatePreview = function (req, res) {
    const filename = `car-wash-2.html`;
    const fullpath = resolvePath(__dirname, filename)
    console.log(fullpath);
}
```

The console.log path is:

```
/Users/blahblah/Desktop/Work/Code/preview-inkto/preview/car-wash-2.html
```

This is the full path and I can confirm it's correct.

```
const html_code = fs.readFileSync(fullpath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
        res.send(`this is the error: ${err}`);
        console.error(err)
        return
    }
    res.send(data);
    return data;
})
```

This hangs and gives me a 504 error.  I'm not sure why it's hanging the path is correct, I would expect for it to return an error if there was an issue reading the file.  If an incorrect path is placed it gives me an error that the path doesn't exist.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `readFileSync` doesn't take a callback. If you want to catch the error use try and catch. You probably wanted to use `readFile` instead

Comment: `fs.readFileSync()` does NOT take a callback.  That would be `fs.readFile()`.